# Why Web API is not finding my resource?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am using Web API 2 and developing in ASP.Net 4. This is a sample code that I trying to learn webapi. There are two routes. The first route is services resource for a given store. The second route is store resource route.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Services",
        url: "store/{id}/services",
        defaults: new { controller = "Services" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Store",
        url: "store/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Store", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
    );
}
```

The second route "Store" works perfectly. The first route is to go in detail of all the services available in the store. When I try

> /api/store/1/services

I get 404 error. Could someone point me to what am I doing wrong?

Here is the controller

```
namespace APITestter1.Controllers
{
    public class ServicesController : ApiController
    {
        public string Get(int id, string prop = "xxx")
        {
            return "Hello services World!" + id + " added attribute " + prop;
        }

        public string Post(int id, string prop = "xxx")
        {
            return "Hello Post World!" + id + " added attribute " + prop;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand why the prefix plus "api" and "prop"?

I update your code:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Services",
            url: "api/store/{id}/services/{prop}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Services", action = "store", prop = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Store",
            url: "store/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Store", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
    }


namespace APITestter1.Controllers
{
    public class ServicesController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet, ActionName="store"]
        public string Get(int id, string prop = "xxx")
        {
            return "Hello services World!" + id + " added attribute " + prop;
        }

        [HttpPost, ActionName="store"]
        public string Post(int id, string prop = "xxx")
        {
            return "Hello Post World!" + id + " added attribute " + prop;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mapping your web api routes in the wrong file. If you are doing web api then look for `WebApiConfig.cs` file and map your web api routes there.

You are also trying to browse to `/api/store/1/services` but in your example you map the route as `store/{id}/services`. Note you don't have `api` in your route template.

The following web api config should match what you are trying to do

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ServicesApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/store/{id}/services",
            defaults: new { controller = "Services" }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

You also say your second route "Store" works perfectly but have not showed what URL you used. Assuming it was `/api/store/1` then it would work because it maps to the `DefaultApi` route template which uses `api/{controller}/{id}`.